# How to show description under an inserted image?

Tags: gallery

I'm using wordpress' native media manager. I have a problem. I can show the title under the image. But I want also to show the description. Is it possible to do?

Comment: How are you defining the description? Post Content? Post Excerpt? Custom Post Meta?

Comment: <textarea id="attachments[706][post_content]" name="attachments[706][post_content]" style=""></textarea>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually quite easy: You just hijack the short code handler for image captions, grab the `post_content` (the image description) and set its content as a value for the attribute `caption`. Then you call the original shortcode handler.

The following example requires the shortcode attribute `desc` set to `1` to make the magic work:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Caption With Description
 * Description: Adds the description to images with a caption if you set <code>desc=1</code> in the shortcode.
 * Version:     2015.03.26
 * Author:      Thomas Scholz <info@toscho.de>
 * Author URI:  http://toscho.de
 * License:     MIT
 * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

namespace T5\Images\Captions;

$callback = __NAMESPACE__ . '\add_description';

// Hijack the native shortcode handlers.
add_shortcode( 'wp_caption', $callback );
add_shortcode( 'caption',    $callback );

/**
 * Add image description if needed
 *
 * @param  array $attr
 * @param  null $content
 * @return string
 */
function add_description( $attr, $content = null )
{
    if ( needs_description( $attr ) )
        $attr['caption'] = get_description( $attr['id'] );

    return img_caption_shortcode( $attr, $content );
}

/**
 * Check required attribute values
 *
 * @param array $attr
 * @return bool
 */
function needs_description( Array $attr ) {

    if ( empty ( $attr['desc'] ) )
        return FALSE;

    if ( 1 > (int) $attr['width'] )
        return FALSE;

    return ! empty ( $attr['id'] );
}

/**
 * Prepare post content (the description)
 *
 * @param  string $attachment_id Usually it looks like 'attachment_123'
 * @return string
 */
function get_description( $attachment_id ) {

    $post_id = str_replace( 'attachment_', '', $attachment_id );
    $img     = get_post( (int) $post_id );

    if ( is_a( $img, 'WP_Post' ) )
        return wpautop( $img->post_content );

    return '';
}
```

Now you add a description …

[image]

… use regular caption markup …

[image]

… and get the description nicely formatted:

[image]

If you add the parameter `desc` with a value different from `1` to the caption (`desc=0` for example) no description will be used.

[Download on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/2318565).

Answer (score 3):

First of all thanks to **toscho** for his solution. In case anybody needs the code for his theme instead of using it as a plugin here is the adopted code rewritten as a single function:

```
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'img_caption_add_description');
add_shortcode('caption', 'img_caption_add_description');
function img_caption_add_description($attr, $content = null)
{
    $post_id = str_replace('attachment_', '', $attr['id']);
    $img = get_post((int)$post_id);

    if (is_a($img, 'WP_Post')) {
        $attr['caption'] = $img->post_content;
    }

    return img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content);
}
```

Tested this with Wordpress 4.2.3 and it's working without any problems.

Comment: how we can change the class name of the description holder?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I wanted to show description under all pictures. This solution works great.Thanks to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3687/tom-auger

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE-45326 Gallery Replacement example
Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45326
Description: A plugin to demonstrate how to replace the default 'gallery' shortcode and add additional HTML tags for more customization.
Version: 1.0
Author: Tom Auger
Author URI: http://www.tomauger.com
License: GPL2
*/

class wpse_45326_Gallery_Replacement {
    function __construct(){
        // Hook on the plugins-loaded action since it's the first real action hook that's available to us.
        // However, if you're using a theme and want to replace that theme's `gallery` custom shortcode,
        // you may need to use another action. Search through your parent theme's files for 'gallery' and see
        // what hook it's using to define it's gallery shortcode, so you can make sure this code runs AFTER their code.
        add_action( "init", array( __CLASS__, "init" ) );
    }

    function init(){
        remove_shortcode( 'gallery' ); // Remove the default gallery shortcode implementation
        add_shortcode( 'gallery', array( __CLASS__, "gallery_shortcode" ) ); // And replace it with our own!
    }

    /**
    * The Gallery shortcode.
    *
    * This has been taken verbatim from wp-includes/media.php. There's a lot of good stuff in there.
    * All you want to do is add some more HTML to it, and since (for some reason) they didn't provide more
    * filters to be able to add, we have to replace the Gallery shortcode wholesale.
    *
    * @param array $attr Attributes of the shortcode.
    * @return string HTML content to display gallery.
    */
    function gallery_shortcode($attr) {
        global $post;

        static $instance = 0;
        $instance++;

        $output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
        if ( $output != '' )
            return $output;

        if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
            $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
            if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
                unset( $attr['orderby'] );
        }

        // NOTE: These are all the 'options' you can pass in through the shortcode definition, eg: [gallery itemtag='p']
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
            'id'         => $post->ID,
            'itemtag'    => 'dl',
            'icontag'    => 'dt',
            'captiontag' => 'dd',
            'columns'    => 3,
            'size'       => 'thumbnail',
            'include'    => '',
            'exclude'    => '',
            // Here's the new options stuff we added to the shortcode defaults
            'titletag'  => 'p',
            'descriptiontag' => 'p'
        ), $attr));

        $id = intval($id);
        if ( 'RAND' == $order )
            $orderby = 'none';

        if ( !empty($include) ) {
            $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
            $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

            $attachments = array();
            foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
                $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
            }
        } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
            $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
            $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
        } else {
            $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
        }

        if ( empty($attachments) )
            return '';

        if ( is_feed() ) {
            $output = "\n";
            foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
                $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
            return $output;
        }

        $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
        $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
        $columns = intval($columns);
        $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
        $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

        $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

        $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
        if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
            $gallery_style = "
            <style type='text/css'>
                #{$selector} {
                    margin: auto;
                }
                #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                    float: {$float};
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    text-align: center;
                    width: {$itemwidth}%;
                }
                #{$selector} img {
                    border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
                }
                #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                    margin-left: 0;
                }
            </style>
            <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->";
        $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
        $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
        $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

        $i = 0;
        foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
            $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

            $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
            $output .= "
                <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                    $link
                </{$icontag}>";

            // MODIFICATION: include the title and description HTML if we've supplied the relevant shortcode parameters (titletag, descriptiontag)
            if ( $captiontag ) {
                $output .= "
                    <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>";
                // The CAPTION, if there is one
                if ( trim( $attachment->post_excerpt ) ) {
                    $output .= "
                        " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt);
                }

                // The TITLE, if we've not made the 'titletag' param blank
                if ( $titletag ){
                    $output .= "
                        <{$titletag} class=\"gallery-item-title\">" . $attachment->post_title . "</{$titletag}>";
                }

                // The DESCRIPTION, if we've not specified a blank 'descriptiontag'
                if ( $descriptiontag ){
                    $output .= "
                        <{$descriptiontag} class=\"gallery-item-description\">" . wptexturize( $attachment->post_content ) . "</{$descriptiontag}>";
                }

                $option .= "
                    </{$captiontag}>";
            }
            $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
            if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
                $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
        }

        $output .= "
                <br style='clear: both;' />
            </div>\n";

        return $output;
    }
}

new wpse_45326_Gallery_Replacement();
```