# Showing image description along with embedded links below post images

Tags: captions, description

I have images in my Wordpress posts with the following field setup:

Caption: This field contains the actual image caption to be displayed below the image.

Description: This field contains photo credits with links to attributed sources.

I need both these values to be displayed right below the image like so:

[image]

Taking cue from an excellent answer from @toscho to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48117/how-to-show-description-under-an-inserted-image) question, I tried this function:

```
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'img_caption_add_description');
add_shortcode('caption', 'img_caption_add_description');
function img_caption_add_description($attr, $content = null)
{
    $post_id = str_replace('attachment_', '', $attr['id']);
    $img = get_post((int)$post_id);

    if (is_a($img, 'WP_Post')) {
        $attr['caption'] = $img->post_content;
    }

    return img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content);
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot, the function does its job well except that it strips off all hyperlinks. I need them! Is there any way to modify the above function in a way that it honors the links? In the above example, for instance, the texts "Amit Schandillia" and "CC BY-SA 3.0", both are meant to be hyperlinks. I have the links alright in my Description field as below:

```
Photo credit: <a href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Amit Schandillia</a> licensed <a href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-creative-commons"></i> BY-SA 3.0</a>
```

How do I make sure the `<a>` tags stay when being rendered on the post page?

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the last line [`img_caption_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/img_caption_shortcode/), then you can see [`wp_kses()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/) stripping non allowed HTML tags there. The [`wp_kses_hook()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_hook/) function does only wrap a filter:

```
return apply_filters( 'pre_kses', $string, $allowed_html, $allowed_protocols );
```

which allows to hook in and alter the output before [`wp_kses_split()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_split/) finally removes the HTML tag by using `preg_replace_callback` with [`_wp_kses_split_callback()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_kses_split_callback/) as function to remove the tags.

As inside `_wp_kses_split_callback()`, the [`wp_kses_split2()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_split2/) function is called, you got a (bad) alternative as well: Altering a global.

You got the following two globals in the callback:

```
global $pass_allowed_html, $pass_allowed_protocols;
```

Meaning that you can do the following as well (not recommended):

```
// Fetch the global context
global $pass_allowed_html;
// Save the global context for restoring it to not nuke other code
$temp = $pass_allowed_html;
// Alter the context
$GLOBALS['pass_allowed_html'] = [ /* your allowed HTML tags here */ ];
// Fetch the result
$result = img_caption_shortcode();
// Reset the global context
$GLOBALS['pass_allowed_html'] = $temp;
// Return your altered result
return $result;
```

Keep in mind that `wp_kses_allowed_html()` will then trigger it's `explicit` case.

As `img_caption_shortcode()` only passes the `string` of value `post` to `wp_kses()`, you can as well then take profit from the following lines inside `wp_kses_split2()`:

```
if ( ! is_array( $allowed_html ) )
    $allowed_html = wp_kses_allowed_html( $allowed_html );
```

Looking at [`wp_kses_allowed_html()`] again:

```
return apply_filters( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', $allowedposttags, $context );
```

you can simply use this filter. Make sure that you [**remove the filter again**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+filter) after it has run to not conflict with other content and therefore allowing the tag elsewhere by accident.